How do I write templates that access a type's member variable but skips if the member variable is not in the type?
I have to set different member variables based on the types supplied to a template. But the problem is all of the members I'm trying to set are not in types that get used by the template.
Ex:
https://www.onlinegdb.com/0UREacEu5
#include <iostream>


struct test1 {
    int a;
};

struct test2 {
    int b;
};

template <class T>
void func(T& test) {
    test.a = 1;
    test.b = 2;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout<<"Hello World";
    test1 t1;
    test2 t2;
    func(t1);
    func(t2);
    return 0;
}

Gives out compilation error:
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void func(T&) [with T = test1]’:
main.cpp:31:9:   required from here main.cpp:23:10: error: ‘struct
test1’ has no member named ‘b’    23 |     test.b = 2;
      |     ~~~~~^ main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void func(T&) [with T = test2]’: main.cpp:32:9:   required from here main.cpp:22:10:
error: ‘struct test2’ has no member named ‘a’    22 |     test.a = 1;
      |     ~~~~~^


You can also just write two different versions(function overloading) if these are the only two classes and members you have.

You can write concepts for checking. Demo c++20

Note the C++20 answer in that linked question is simpler than the answers for older C++ standards.

As there is already a dupe I've deleted my answer here and closed this as dupe.
